# Dompdf footer not set..?

Tags: php, footer, dompdf

Here I am using the dompdf for generating pdf with some header,body,footer.
But when i try to add the footer ,it's not attaching.

It always come with the body code,
I want to set a footer at bottom.

Can anyone figure-out that where i am wrong with the below code ?

**Code :**

```
    global $_dompdf_show_warnings;
    global $_dompdf_debug;
    global $_DOMPDF_DEBUG_TYPES;
    global $_dompdf_warnings;
    $_dompdf_show_warnings = FALSE;

    require_once(realpath(APPPATH."third_party/dompdf")."/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper("letter", "portrait");

    $html = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>
                    </title>
                    </head>

`enter code here`                  <body style="margin:0; background-color:#ff9900; color:#ffffff;">
                        <div>
                            <div style="margin:15px;">
                                <div>
                                    <span style="font-size:25px; font-weight:600;">
                                        Hi, John
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>
                                        Your account statement is here.
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div style="margin-top:15px; border: 2px solid;border-radius:5px; padding:10px; position:absolute; diplay:block;">
                                    <div style="float:left;">left</div>
                                    <div style="float:right;">right</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="background-color:#ffffff; color:#ff9900; position:fixed; bottom:0;width:100%;padding:10px;">
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                    <b><i>This is a system generated statement.</i></b>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                   <b><i> If you have any queries, email support@xyz.com.</i></b>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>';


        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();

        $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

Comment: You have a random "`enter code here`" text in your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

In dompdf (up to and including version 0.7.0) elements are (generally speaking) rendered starting with the page on which they first appear. Because of this you'll want to put any fixed content (ex. header/footer set to fixed) at the top of your document.

Reference: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/688#issuecomment-21818867